# raspiberry pi pjsip compile error: emmintrin.h no such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, pjsip

I'm trying to compile PJSIP (version 2.6) on my Raspberry Pi 3 model B.

While running `make dep && make`, I get this error:

```
../../webrtc/src/webrtc//system_wrappers/source/cpu_features.cc                                                             
../../webrtc/src/webrtc//modules/audio_processing/aec/aec_core_sse2.c:15:23: fatal error: emmintrin.h: No such file or directory    
 #include <emmintrin.h>                                                                                                             
                       ^                                                                                                            
compilation terminated.                                                                                                             
../../webrtc/src/webrtc//modules/audio_processing/aec/aec_rdft_sse2.c:13:23: fatal error: emmintrin.h: No such file or directory    
 #include <emmintrin.h>                                                                                                             
                       ^                                                                                                            
compilation terminated.
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the exact same issue trying to do exactly what you are doing.

I found a few solutions online but was not satisfied with any of them. They all seemed like nasty hacks.

I looked into the `configure` script and discovered that `sse2` is only required for compiling `libwebrtc`, which I did not need. Thus I simply disabled the compilation of `libwebrtc` alongside other things that I didn't need:

```
 ./configure --disable-sdl --disable-ffmpeg --disable-v4l2 --disable-openh264 --disable-libwebrtc
```

Note that `--disable-v4l2` is referencing `video4linux2`.

After that the compilation completed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this was solved in this thread: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=178384